# Check leap year

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that runs every month for previous month. So in March it should run for Feb and if it is a leap year, it should return 29 else 28.

```
REM set Month=%date:~4,2%
set Month=03
set /A leapyear=%date:~10,4%
set /A remainder = %leapyear%%4

if %Month%==03 if %remainder%==0 (set DateVal = 29) else (set DateVal = 28)
echo %DateVal%
```

The value for remainder is returned as 2020 and the if condition fails. What could be wrong?

D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>set Month=03

D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>set /A leapyear=2020

**D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>set /A remainder = 2020**

D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>if 03 == 03 if 2020 == 0 (set DateVal = 29 )  else (set DateVal = 28 )

D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Extracts\Audit_Extracts>

Comment: It should just be `set /A remainder = leapyear %% 4`  The percent symbol for the mod must be doubled in a batch file the same way you have to double the percent symbol with the `FOR` command.  Percent symbols are not required for  variable names when using the `/A` option with the `SET` command.  But if you really want to use it then it would look like this: `set /A remainder = %leapyear% %% 4`  You should be able to see all of that in the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: `set DateVal = 29` assigns the value _space_ + `29` to a variable called `DateVal` + _space_, so you have to remove the _spaces_ around the `=`-sign…

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic call to a function that I use to get the last day of the month. Usage is in REM statement.

```
@echo off &setlocal
CLS

REM Gets last day of month
REM Send the 4 digit year 2 digit month and a return variable to set the last day to.
call :DaysOfMonth 2016 02 last
echo Last Day Of Month: %last%
pause
goto :eof


:DaysOfMonth Year Month
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /a "yy = %~1, mm = 100%~2 %% 100"
set /a "n = 30 + !(((mm & 9) + 6) %% 7) + !(mm ^ 2) * (!(yy %% 4) - !(yy %% 100) + !(yy %% 400) - 2)"
endlocal &set "%~3=%n%"
```

Comment: This is helpful. But I would like to understand why "set /A remainder = %leapyear%%4" returns 2020 instead of 0. When I run it separately in the command prompt as a command it returns 0. But when I run it in the script, it returns 2020.

Comment: Also, the if condition doesn't seem to be working. if I change the month to 04, it should return 28. But it still returns 29. I have removed the spaces.

Comment: @user1492218 please do not post comments under an answer that has nothing to do with the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a batch script, the Modulus operator (%) must always be doubled up to (%%).
You can also make things a bit clearer by omitting the %'s from variable names when using
SET /A. [See here](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)